# How to set proxy header in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http, proxy, network-programming, httpurlconnection

I am trying to build an HTTP request to be sent via a proxy that accepts a proxy header. I am trying to find a way to set that, but couldn't see it.

Below is the curl command which I need to convert to the Java code.

curl -i -u user:pwd -k GET --http1.1 --proxy-insecure https://localhost:8443 --proxy-header "X-Connect-Client-Id: abcde" https://target_host/api

This is what I was trying to do.
`

```
        Properties systemSettings = System.getProperties();
        systemSettings.put("proxySet", "true");
        systemSettings.put("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
        systemSettings.put("http.proxyPort", "8443");
        URL url = new URL("https://target_host/api");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        byte[] message = ("user:pwd").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String basicAuth = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(message);
        con.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuth);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");`
```

Comment: This sort of documentation is overlooked, too, the correct IETF RFC's , this link for msdn can help though not an answer, note, has RFC syntax semantics in example break downs  https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html#field.proxy-authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add headers in by calling `setRequestProperty` method:

```
Properties systemSettings = System.getProperties();
systemSettings.put("proxySet", "true");
systemSettings.put("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
systemSettings.put("http.proxyPort", "8443");
URL url = new URL("https://target_host/api");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
byte[] message = ("user:pwd").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String basicAuth = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(message);
con.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuth);
con.setRequestProperty("X-Connect-Client-Id", "abcde");
con.setRequestMethod("GET");`
```

Comment: Thanks @Leonardo Emmanuel de Azevedo for answering. Yes, setting as request property should be the way to go it seems. 
But for some reason, I am getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. 

Not sure, what's causing this. The target url works with basic authentication.

Comment: That's a completely different issue. It's related to certificates. Looks like your client is not accepting the certificate the server is requesting. Can you add the server certificate to your keystore and try again?